# Can i change color black to other color?

Tags: c++, opencv

Can i change color black to other color?

I was made area use this code :

```
void MainWindow::division_image_level1()
{
    ROI_Vertices1.clear();
    ROI_Vertices1.push_back(Point(196,40));   
    ROI_Vertices1.push_back(Point(47,450));
    ROI_Vertices1.push_back(Point(204,450)); 
    ROI_Vertices1.push_back(Point(275,40));

    Mat mask1(m_WebcamRead.size(), CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));

    approxPolyDP(ROI_Vertices1, ROI_Poly1, 1.0, true);

    fillConvexPoly(mask1, &ROI_Poly1[0], ROI_Poly1.size(), 255, 8, 0);

    Mat cut_image1(ROI_Poly1.size(), ROI_Poly1.size(), CV_8UC4);

    m_WebcamRead.copyTo(cut_image1, mask1);

    namedWindow("cnt_line_1");
    imshow("cnt_line_1",cut_image1);
    cnt_line_1 = detect_line(cut_image1);
    std::cout <<"cnt_line_1 : "<<cnt_line_1 <<std::endl;
}
```

I will call this area is 'My area' and other area is 'Background area'

```
int MainWindow::detect_line(Mat detected_image)         
{
    Mat HSV;
    cvtColor(detected_image, HSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
    cv::Scalar hsv_user_low(0, 0, 0);
    cv::Scalar hsv_user_high(150, 150, 150);
    inRange(HSV,hsv_user_low,hsv_user_high,HSV);
    int cnt_line=0;
    cnt_line= countNonZero(HSV);       
    return cnt_line;
}
```

I want to get a signal when black color come in 'My area'. 
But `detect_line` function always realized 'Background area' color is black. 
I wish `detect_line` function would know difference between these two.
What should I do? ( How can i change 'Background area' color black to white? )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV Python - Set background colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810128/opencv-python-set-background-colour)

Comment: Please share the images that you're working with, to illustrate the issue that you're facing